# Anoxic sample containers

Tags: experimental-technique

I am preparing pure Si samples, etching the oxide layer, in an argon glovebox, and I have to transfer them to the AFM. We don't have any sample containers in the lab, so I have to buy some. I wasn't able to find any containers that would prevent my samples from oxygen and water exposure. What kind of containers are typically used to transfer oxygen-sensitive samples and what are they called?

Answer (score 1):

After half a year exposure to experimental work in the field, I know there are two options:

- Eppendorf tubes, [Sigma link](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/z768790). 
  [image: Eppendorf tubes, By Nadine90 [CC BY-SA 3.0] (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), via Wikimedia Commons]
  They are typically used to store powder materials, and they offer some degree of oxygen protection. However, a second option is better and more expensive.
- Cryogenic tubes, [Sigma link](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/cls430491). 
  [image: Cryo tubes, image from sigmaaldrich.com]
  They have rubber o-rings to prevent oxygen leaks (denoted in product description as *PlugSeal*, *washer* or *O-ring*).